# What is a good value for "Access log destination ARN"

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

So I go to my API stage and click the button labeled "Custom access logging"

Then I copy the ARN of the log group that I just created into the field labeled Access log destination ARN.

Then I enter my log format and click save. Hidden behind a green badge that says "Successfully updated logging and tracing settings for ''. There is a red one that says "Access log destination must only contain characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9, '_', '-', '/', '.'"

Okay, that seems to tell me that the colon and the '*' that come when I copy the ARN of the log group are not allowed, so I try just the name of the log group. That gets me another error message saying that ARN has to start with "ARN:".

So finally, I shaved the ":*" off of the end of the value that I get when I copy the ARN of the log group, I still get the same error message implying that ':' is not allowed, but the GUI also tells me that custom logging is now active and the ARN, which of course has ':' characters in it, appears to be the right one.

So I think I may have answered my own question: This is a bug in the AWS web console. The regex that produces the notification is wrong, and the text of the red badge notification is also incorrect.

Or have I?

Answer (score 0):

The arn you get when you copy from "log group details" is for all of the logstreams in the log group - that asterisk is a wildcard denoting "any log stream". So this arn will match any resource like `arn:aws:logs:region:account-id:log-group:log_group_name:log-stream:log-stream-name`.

The arn for the log group itself, not contents of it, is indeed the part before the asterisk (see [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/iam-access-control-overview-cwl.html#CWL_ARN_Format)).

The error about the `:` character was probably just not dismissed the first time around. The message you get is accurate as it states that the *log destination* cannot contain `:` (log destination, as mentioned in the doc, is the last part of the arn, not the whole string).